# TensorFlow Keras Custom Callbacks on_test_begin doesn't override itself

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom callback that activates at the beginning and end of the training and validation parts when I call model.fit(...)

The training part (on_train_begin/on_train_end) works perfectly fine, but the testing part(on_test_begin/on_test_end) isn't called. In PyCharm, it doesn't even show the methods as ones that already exist. For the train ones, I get the override sign on the left but not for the tests ones.

How can I create a custom callback that will activate during the validation? I'm on TensorFlow 1.13(not sure if that changes anything).

I want to do that in order to be able to record the execution time of the training and the execution time of the validation.

I followed instruction from the official TensorFlow website :

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback

I also found the methods on_test_begin and on_test_end on the official website:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard

```py
class TimeHistory(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_test_begin(slef,logs=None):
        print('testing begins')
    def on_test_end(selfs,logs=None):
        print('testing ends')
    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        print("training begins")
    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        print('training ends')

def creationModeleMLP(nbHiddenLayers,nbPerceptrons,nbEpochs,learningRate,myBatchSize,currentFold):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    #ajoute le input layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(76,)))
    #ajoute les hidden layers
    for i in range(nbHiddenLayers):
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nbPerceptrons, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    #ajoute le output layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learningRate),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    #entraine le modele
    timeHistory = TimeHistory()
    histoire = model.fit(vectPrimTrain[currentFold], typeTrain[currentFold], batch_size=myBatchSize, epochs=nbEpochs,
              callbacks=[tensorboard,timeHistory], validation_data=(vectPrimTest[currentFold],typeTest[currentFold]))
```

I expect the method on_test_begin and the method on_test_end to be called at the start of the validation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `on_test_*` and `on_predict_*` have been added to tensorflow 1.14+. Make sure you have tensorflow 1.14 or tensorflow 2 to be able to use those.

Comment: I upgraded to tensorflow 1.14 as you suggested and it worked. I was using 1.13.1 because that was the lastest version available on conda. To install the 1.14 I used ```pip install tensorflow==1.14```